# My Home Bank doesn·t work well

Tags: java, browser

Using Firefox or Chromium it·s not possible to pay bills or transfer money on Itau website. I was able to do this at Ubuntu 11.10. It demand to install a java script on browser, but it not occur. My open JDK Java is 7.

Comment: FYI:  That's Java, not Javascript.  There is a *big* difference.

Answer (score 1):

try to install the package icedtea7-plugin

open a terminal and follow the fowling comands

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin
```